# Delphi .exe after build error

Tags: delphi, fastreport

good day! i have a project and it runs perfectly, i did that project 3 months ago. Then, i tried to put some changes  and even BUILD ONLY the project (no additional codes). When i open the .EXE it appears errors like this.

[image]

when i clicked DON'T SEND

[image]

and when i clicked OK

[image]

When i opened the form this message appers:
[image]

How to fixed it? I really need to add some functions to that project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to know what to fix without knowing anything about your project, what it does, and what your code looks like. It appears that the issue comes from some PDF Export though...

Comment: It appears to be Fast Reports you're using, right?

Comment: could you provide us with more info about your project .

Comment: @JerryDodge yes sir, im using Fast Reports.

Comment: Don't use JPG for non-photographic images, like screenshots...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - there are no rules here about what your preferred format is, as long as it's a sensible size and can be viewed.

Comment: The JPG artifacts seen on non-photographic images (incorrectly) saved as JPG (a format intended for photographic images) drive my crazy. PNG was invented to be used in such cases.

Comment: I agree with Andreas, although it's off-topic to the actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have updated the component used, which looks like Fast Reports. You need to open up the form in Delphi and the new property will be added by Delphi. Any other forms that use the same component will also need to be opened up to update the properties.

When the error reading form message comes up, click ignore. This should add the missing property. You will want to view the DFM as text to make sure the property has been added.

Comment: i opened all forms and there's a one form has error message, kindly look at the question above. thanks sir!

Comment: I believe ignore is the correct response. You'll want to view the DFM as text and look for that component. You should now see the property there.

Answer (score 3):

Your .dfm file refers to a property that is not published by the component which is being streamed. The streaming framework is attempting to read into a property named `Quality` of an object named `frxPDFExport1`. And that object does not publish a property of that name.

Most likely there's a mismatch between the design time package that you used to generate the .dfm file, and the run time component that is reading that .dfm file. Have you upgraded one and not the other recently?

I'm afraid I cannot give you precise steps to fix the problem, but what I describe above is what is happening. Hopefully that will be enough to lead you to the solution.

Comment: The component associated with the error. The thing named `frxPDFExport1`.